# Returning from a DbSet 3 tables without the error "cannot be inferred from the query"

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

I have 3 classes. WorkoutSession, WorkoutSessionExercise and Exercise.

I would like to return the WorkoutSession **with** its list of WorkoutSession **with** the Exercise related. WorkoutSession has many WorkoutSessionExercise, and these one has only a single 1 to 1 relationship with Exercise.

```
             var query = from workoutSession in DatabaseContext.SetOwnable<WorkoutSession>()
             from workoutSessionExercises in workoutSession.WorkoutSessionExercises
             from exerciseInfo in workoutSessionExercises.Exercise
             where workoutSession.Id == id
             select workoutSession;
```

The last FROM has the error : The type argument cannot be inferred from the query.

How can I load this three level deep objects with Linq To Entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
DatabaseContext.SetOwnable<WorkoutSession>
    .Include("WorkoutSessionExercises.Exercise")
    .Where(w => w.Id == id);
```

Alternate syntax:

```
from workoutSession in DatabaseContext.SetOwnable<WorkoutSession>
    .Include("WorkoutSessionExercises.Exercise")
    where workoutSession.Id == id
    select workoutSession;
```

The key here is that `Include` method - this allows you to indicate which related objects should be hydrated.

**Edit**

Try this to get around the string-based includes (inspiration from [Include nested entities using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179061/linq-nested-entities)):

```
var query = from workoutSession in DatabaseContext.SetOwnable<WorkoutSession>
select new
{
     WorkoutSession,
     WorkoutSessionExercises = from workoutSessionExercise in
        DatabaseContext.SetOwnable<WorkoutSessionExercises>
        select new
        {
            WorkoutExercise = from workoutExercise in
                DatabaseContext.SetOwnable<WorkoutExercise>
                select workoutExercise
        }
};

var results = query.Select(r => r.WorkoutSession).Where(w => w.Id == id);
```

Comment: I'll give it a try when I come back to this project in few hours. Of course, what I dislike is the use of string but if it can work, it's better than nothing.

Comment: +1, this solution works well. Thank you. I will try to make work the solution of Diego which doesn't work for the moment because it's more "clean" than using String. Yours works and it's the goal for the moment.

Comment: Edited my answer with a string-free approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = DatabaseContext.SetOwnable<WorkoutSession>()
                           .Include(x => x.WorkoutSessionExercises
                                          .Select(e => e.Exercise))
                           .Where(x => x.Id == id);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I will take a further look soon because I like the way it avoid using strings.

Comment: Tonight, i'll post the exact error message, but it still contains the inferred error (from my memory).